# Why is GLM Perspective projection acting like Orthographic Projection

Tags: c++, opengl, projection, glm-math, perspectivecamera

I Have a projection matrix in my C++ OpenGL Application.

```cpp
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
```

This Matrix is later sent as uniform to the Vertex Shader ->

```cpp
Nade::Shader::SetMat4(app.shader->GetProgram(), "p", app.projection);
```

And Utilized inside the Vertex Shader

```cpp
gl_Position = m * p * vec4(pos,1.0);
```

And then the Rendered Quad is moved at the Z Axis

```cpp
object.Translate(0, 0, -0.05);
```

**Observed Behavior**: The Rendered Mesh behaves like it is within a Orthographic Matrix where it stays same in size but clips away at the far point

**Expected Behavior**: The Rendered Mesh reduces in size and clips away.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `m * p * vec4(pos,1.0);`: This applies `p` before `m`.

Comment: @Frank my life is a lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl_Position = m * p * vec4(pos,1.0);` is equivalent to `gl_Position = m * (p * vec4(pos,1.0));`, which means that the position is transformed by `p` before being transformed by `m`.

Assuming `p` means "projection" and `m` means "modelview", then it should be:

`gl_Position = p * m * vec4(pos,1.0);`

You might be wondering: **Why didn't this cause issues earlier?**

With an orthographic projection, and a camera looking down the `z` axis, the original code could still look like it works. That's because a zero-centered orthographic projection is basically just a scaling matrix.